# Windows: How can I diagnose certificate revocation check failure, when I know the OK response is sent?

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl, ocsp, exchange-server

TL;DR; How to discover what is wrong with OCSP response on Windows?

I am trying to install a new certificate in on-premises Exchange Server 2019. But Exchange always reports that the new certificate fails the revocation check and will not use it. The new certificate has a chain of trust from the new cert, through an intermediate CA to my root ca. When I open the new cert in certmgr.msc, I see that that chain, and all certificates are reported as OK in certmgr. I have installed my root CA into the “Trusted Root Certification Authorities” store. I have installed the intermediate CA into the “Intermediate  Certification Authorities” store.

The new cert’s **Authority Info Access** URL specifies my own OCSP responder. I know this is not a connection nor proxy problem, because I watch the OCSP logs real-time, and I know the connection is made, and my OCSP responder sends cert “OK”. I have tested with openssl-ocsp on a linux host, and that validation succeeds, when I use this openssl command:

```
   openssl ocsp 
      -issuer "$ca_sub_cert_file" 
      -cert "$exchangeCert" 
      -resp_text 
      -CApath "$CA_ROOTS_HASHES_DIR" 
      -url "http://$hostNameFull:$ocsp_port/"
```

Please note that the above openssl command explicitly refers to the *issuer*, and the *CApath*, and that enables trust upon the intermediate CA. On Windows, I expected that installing the root-ca and the intermediate CA would similarly enable trust for the OCSP response. But I do not know how to test this.

It should not be necessary, but I also “installed” a certificate for the ocsp-responder. I allowed the wizard to choose the store automatically, and I can not find where it was put. It does not appear when I search for it in certmgr.msc. I have not installed it manually, because I do not know which store I should use.

I suspect that the response from my openssl OCSP responder is wrong for Exchange Server 2019. My theories are:

- A trust chain cannot be built from the new certificate to my root
  CA
- The chain is built, but one of the certificates for
  ocsp-responder, the intermediate-ca, or root-ca is not trusted. Even
  though intermediate-ca, and root-ca are installed.
- The openSSL
  response is incompatible with Windows and or  Exchange Server 2019

How can I test the above theories? I searched the windows event logs but they do not contain any mention of OCSP or revocation.

Comment: I don't think that OCSP is your problem. Your problem is most likely in CRL. Post the output of the following command: `certutil -verify -urlfetch exchcert.cer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `certutil.exe` has a relatively new option, called `-downloadocsp` which you can use to verify the OCSP responses.

1. In a command prompt, create two folders, called `certs` and `results`.
2. Place your Exchange server certificates in the `certs` folder.  If your using OCSP to check the CA certificate too, place a copy of the CA certificate in that folder.
3. Run `certutil -downloadocsp certs results downloadonce`.  This will create a `.ocsp` file within `results` for each response.
4. Finally, run `certutil results\????.ocsp` to view each response as plaintext.

The above is from Mark Cooper's brilliant [website](https://www.pkisolutions.com/new-certutil-argument-downloadocsp-and-details-of-caching-issue-with-verify/).

Comment: Thanks a million! I tried the above: not on my exchange server, but on a Windows 10 workstation. I watch certutil make a connection to my ocsp responder, and it downloads something, but it reports "Error => Pending OCSP response download". Nothing is created in the results directory. At least now I have s tool to work with, and some documentation to read.

Comment: I consistently get nothing in results, and the error " Error => Pending OCSP response download -- <8958F37AF76E2151B548E950719789A1FA705F0A> <saratoga.candy-land.name> <ca-sub.candyland.org> <saratoga.candy-land.name_exchange_20210630145440_exchange.p7b>"

   ... ... ... I get nothing real from google searching for certutil "Pending OCSP response download"

Comment: I can't help you there as I can't get it to error - it works for me when I run it against a certificate I've downloaded from the Internet (GMail in this instance).